# How to Display Difference between two Dates in Numbers of Weeks and Number of Days of Weeks

Tags: flutter, dart, datetime, calculator

I need to get the numbers of ( weeks and days) between 2 dates.
If day reachs 7 then it turns to 0 and add one 1 to the weeks .
A weeks never pass to mounths althought the value is increasing everytime .
for exemple :
Date : 01/01/2022 ,
Today : 05/03/2022 ,
the difference between he two days is : 8 weeks and 5 days .
here is the picture i'm showing exemple of UI :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hFR6M.png)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use `DateTime` object to create 2 objects, then use `DateTime.differece()`  the you can get the number of day using `inDay` and finally divide by 7 and round the output to be the number of weeks then the difference will be the number of day

```
from = DateTime(from.year, from.month, from.day);
to = DateTime(to.year, to.month, to.day);
totalDays = to.difference(from).inDays
of (totalDays < 7) {
    daysDiff = totalDays
} else {
totalFullWeeks = (totalDay / 7).ceil()
daysDiff = totalDay - totalFullWeeks*7
}
```

Comment: thank you for answering my question , actually i tried your code but it didn't work because it doesnt reach 7 , i dont know whats wrong .. here im showing the screenshot of printing code in the google drive link : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1aPoqvh1b_cshO3gtGCufNPpU6fO2qpEw/view?usp=sharing

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/13MiY-IyKHO3Dsqgh047mSgSyO7JEqm3q/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Replace `round()` with `ceil()` and add add the condition of `if(totalDays < 7) daysDiff = totalDays`

Comment: the problem was in `round()` when ever it's above .5 it rounds to 1 which results in adding another week to the last equation and this why it's some times give you a negative number, my bad.

Comment: thank you for answering ^^ , i solved the problem by replacing round() with .truncate() and found bug with date picker third-party lib so i changed anouther plugin and now it works just fine ^^